# Angular summernote not working with webpack?

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack

We are working on AngularJs version 1.5.10 project. Now we want to move it to Angular 5/6 version.

The application was earlier built using JHipster but we have removed JHipster now.

All of the dependencies of bower has been moved to package.json.

Now we are trying to bundle the scripts using webpack version is 4.26.1

In project summernote version angular-summernote@0.8.1 was used. But now when we are trying to run the webpack to created the bundled JS we are getting below error :

```
C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade>npm run build

> library-app@0.0.0 build C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade
> rimraf src/main/webapp/dist && webpack --mode development --bail --progress --profile

 70% building 66/72 modules 6 active ...de\node_modules\ng-file-upload\index.jsModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular-summernote' in 'C:\MY_DRIVE\Projec
ts\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\src\main\webapp\app'
    at factory.create (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:821:10)
    at factory (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:397:22)
    at resolver (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21)
    at asyncLib.parallel (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22)
    at C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2825:7
    at C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:6886:13
    at normalResolver.resolve (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25)
    at doResolve (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:184:12)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn42 (eval at create (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:390:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:37)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at args (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\forEachBail.js:30:14)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
resolve 'angular-summernote' in 'C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\src\main\webapp\app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\package.json (relative path: ./src/main/webapp/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\src\main\webapp\app\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\src\main\webapp\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\src\main\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\MY_DRIVE\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules
        using description file: C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote\package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote is not a file
            .webpack.js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote.webpack.js doesn't exist
            .web.js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote.web.js doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote.tsx doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                using path: C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote\index
                  using description file: C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote\package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote\index doesn't exist
                    .webpack.js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote\index.webpack.js doesn't exist
                    .web.js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote\index.web.js doesn't exist
                    .ts
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote\index.ts doesn't exist
                    .tsx
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote\index.tsx doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\MY_DRIVE\Projects\MyProject\AngularUpgrade\node_modules\angular-summernote\index.js doesn't exist
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! library-app@0.0.0 build: `rimraf src/main/webapp/dist && webpack --mode development --bail --progress --profile`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/src/main/webapp/dist',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {            
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
        alias: {
            codemirror: './path/to/fake/codemirror'
        }
    },
       module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                use: [
                    {loader: 'ts-loader'},
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I have tried the solutions given at :

- https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote/issues/158
- https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1171

But nothing worked.

How can I resolve the issue?